# Ubuntu + new user + ImportError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I create a new user in Ubuntu16.04. But I can't import tensorflow in the new user. It hint me that, `ImportError: No module named 'google'`

I use the `tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0 + cuda-9.0 + cudnn-7.0` and python 3.5

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
`>>>`import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named 'google'
```

Comment: Have you installed tensorflow?

Comment: Yes,of course,and the exist user could use the tensorflow well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried the command:

```
pip3 install google --user
```

?

Comment: No,but I have solved the problem by trying to update to tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0 .